# VS2019 AWS TOOLKIT FAILED TO INSTALL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, aws-lambda

When I am trying to install AWS Toolkit for VS 2017-2019 from Visual studio Marketplace,I am getting below error .I have already tried repairing my VS 2019 but no luck.I've tried to run this package several times without success.It seems to be failing because of Certificate is invalid: AWSToolkitPackage.vsix
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Cache failed. Retrying download of '12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119,version=1.18.0.0'.Value cannot be null.Parameter name: uri

```
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - 16.6.2051
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - Command line parameters:
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:16.6.30225.117,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\anubhatnagar\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIX3jyhbbul.vsix,/callingprocessid:10612,/installas:2196
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - -------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:45 PM - Initializing Install...
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM - Extension Details...
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Identifier         : 12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Name               : AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Author             : Amazon Web Services
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Version            : 1.18.0.0
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Description        : The AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio is an extension for Microsoft Visual Studio on Windows that makes it easier for developers to develop, debug, and deploy .NET applications using Amazon Web Services. With the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio, you'll be able to get started faster...
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   Locale             : en-US
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   MoreInfoURL        : https://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6,)
7/2/2020 6:38:46 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   SignatureState     : InvalidCertificate
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   SignedBy           : Amazon.com, Inc.
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   Certificate Info   : 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       -------------------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Subject]       : CN="Amazon.com, Inc.", O="Amazon.com, Inc.", L=Seattle, S=Washington, C=US
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Issuer]        : CN=Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA - G2, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Serial Number] : 2B778385004F4CA691C07F3590C07B7F
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Not Before]    : 7/10/2017 5:30:00 AM
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Not After]     : 7/11/2020 5:29:59 AM
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       [Thumbprint]    : D2038C3D2E59604D9AD05674B21B53EA40ACE63F
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   Supported Products : 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -           Version : [15.0,17.0)
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   References         : 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   Prerequisites      : 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       -------------------------------------------------------
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       Name         : Visual Studio core editor
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       Version      : [15.0,17.0)
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - Signature Details...
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -   Extension is signed with an invalid certificate
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       (PartialChain)      : A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       (RevocationStatusUnknown): The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM -       (OfflineRevocation) : The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - 
7/2/2020 6:38:50 PM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
7/2/2020 6:38:51 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL 
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodingConventions\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Commands\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CrossRepositorySearch\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DesignTools\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ErrorList\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\FSharp\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\InteractiveWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\LanguageServer\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NavigateTo\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NuGet\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\OpenFolder\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Performance Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProjectServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProjectSystemQuery\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\RazorLanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ReferenceManager\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Search\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Terminal\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TextMate\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TypeScript\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\UniversalFlavor\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows.Forms\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlLanguageService\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\CPUSampling\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Database\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Debugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\DotNetAsync\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\DotNetObjectAlloc\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\EventsViewer\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Instrumentation\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\ParallelDebugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\PerfMarkers\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Shell\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\SnapshotDebugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\TreeNavigation\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\GraphProviderPackage\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\AppAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\AppResponsiveness\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editorconfig\Wizard\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ExtensionManager\ServiceModule\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\JSDiagnostics\Debugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Language\GenerateType\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\SCC Code Lenses\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestWindow\Profiler\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\Debugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\LanguageServer\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Editors\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\ASPX\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Exports\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\NavigateTo\FileProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\TreeNavigation\GraphProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Visual Studio MPF\16.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ManagedProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeBinary\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeCode\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeProgressiveReveal\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Solution\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\ExpressionEvaluators\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LiveUnitTesting\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\SourceBasedTestDiscovery\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ChromeDebugAdapter\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\EdgeDebugAdapter\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\Node2DebugAdapter\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\WebDiagnosticsAttach\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\SDK ARM Additions\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:38:59 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Windows Store SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
7/2/2020 6:39:00 PM - Skipping 'C:\Users\anubhatnagar\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
7/2/2020 6:39:00 PM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019...
7/2/2020 6:39:00 PM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Update Configuration task has not been successfully registered.
7/2/2020 6:39:00 PM - The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed
7/2/2020 6:39:05 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.8: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.2,6.3)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:05 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.81: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.3,6.4)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:05 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1.1,10.0.16299]'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DbgHelp.Win8: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote.DbgHelp.Win8: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote.DbgHelp.Win8: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.PowershellBindingRedirect: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.7: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:06 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Windows Installer found the package 'msodbcsql,version=16.0.62006.3200,chip=x64,language=en-US' superseded but corresponding compatible package information was not found. Attempts to repair will be skipped and that to uninstall may leave the cache behind.
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.D3DCompiler.Msu.Win7: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1.1,6.4)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Ancm.IIS.Msi: Required conditions are not satisfied: IISCoreWebEngineInstalledx64 And IISW3SvcInstalledx64
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Ancmv2.IIS.Msi: Required conditions are not satisfied: IISCoreWebEngineInstalledx64 And IISW3SvcInstalledx64
7/2/2020 6:39:07 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell: Required conditions are not satisfied: Not Powershell5
7/2/2020 6:39:08 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WindowsIdentityFoundation.Msu: The current OS Version '10.0.17763.0' is not in the supported version range '(,6.2)'.
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Certificate is invalid: AWSToolkitPackage.vsix
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Cache failed. Retrying download of '12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119,version=1.18.0.0'.
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Activity threw exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Skipping cache of package '12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119,version=1.18.0.0' since installing or downloading it failed
7/2/2020 6:39:40 PM - Skipping cache of package 'Component.12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119,version=1.18.0.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
7/2/2020 6:40:38 PM - Install Error : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package '12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119' failed to download
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package '12ed248b-6d4a-47eb-be9e-8eabea0ff119' failed to download
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Comment: Are you working from home without any restrictions or are you working for a company that could have a lot of firewall restrictions?

Comment: @Moojjoo thats what fixed it for me. I had to run IE as admin so i can change the proxy in internet options > connections > LAN settings

Answer (score 0):

Hi I encountered the same problem.

My problem came from my force close the update of msvs.

The update process created some file.

You need to open msvs installer and resume the update you need do last time.
After you finish this update.

you can do yours.